# Changing cursor position using arrow cursor keycode in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor

My editor area:

```
<div id="myeditor" contenteditable="true"><div>
```

I could send and display keycodes using

```
$("#myeditor").text($("#myeditor").text() + String.fromCharCode(65))
```

which it displays "A" in my div of id 'myeditor'. But I am stuck sending Arrow Cursor Keycode to it. (left : 37; up : 38; right: 39; down : 40)

```
$("#myeditor").text($("#myeditor").text() + String.fromCharCode(39))
```

Ahh it doesnt work.. it is showing other ascii character (like ampersand or quote sign) which arent intended. Can you tell me a right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reason is, all other characters are from keys that have some character associated with it. But arrow keys do not have ←,→ such characters associated with them. They just have some functions. Have you ever used arrow keys to input an arrow in a text box?

If you really want to use them to input arrows, you can do the following in your jQuery..

```
var element = $('#myeditor'),
    elementText = element.text();
    store = {
        37: "&larr;",
        38: "&uarr;",
        39: "&rarr;",
        40: "&darr;"
    };

element.keydown(function( event ) {
    var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
         //getSelection gets the selected range of text, when nothing is selected,selection is empty.getRangeAt(0)makes selection from the start of selection.
    var keyCode = event.which;
    if( store[ keyCode ]) {
        var n = document.createElement('span');
            //Adds a new html element.
        n.innerHTML = store[keyCode];
            //Adds the arrow to the newly created html element.
        selection.insertNode( n );
            //insert the newly created html element.
    }
});
```

## [Demo Fiddle by Connor →](http://jsfiddle.net/eXr2n/6/)

or http://jsfiddle.net/ybPzP/10/

Comment: @Connor Is it better now? Not doing that appends the arrow on newer line.

Comment: A lot better, why are you setting the `text` that doesn't change anything, check this demo I made **http://jsfiddle.net/eXr2n/3/**

Comment: and also you can do this in your code `var code = e.keyCode || e.which;`

Comment: @Connor okay. But just appending it adds the arrow to a new line, thats not desirable.

Comment: Then using `text` is not desireable either, your wan't to insert it at the caret position?

Comment: If you look at the demo properly you will see that wherever you put the cursor, that is where the arrow is placed.

Comment: @Connor Oh right that's necessary. I should change my answer then.

Comment: @Connor Can I directly link demo to your fiddle, if you don't mind?

Comment: You can use the whole thing, but you must be able to explain what is going on and how it works so go to **Mozilla Developer Network** And read up on `getSelection & getRangeAt & insertNode`

Comment: thanks for the reply but it is not that arrow sign that i need. it is that i want to move the cursor position.

Comment: @user2168042 You can change the cursor position after you type something into it. http://jsfiddle.net/wQCku/1/ I can use the arrow keys perfectly.

Comment: problem is while typing. While typing cursor is placed at the beginning of the line. I want it to move with last typed characters. And yes, i can use arrow keys perfectly manually.

Comment: i know problem lies with `$("#dtext").text($("#dtext").text() + key);`
i need another way to work around.

Comment: Where does your question say these things?

Comment: And it is not at the first character, but the cursor is placed wherever you click as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I used String.fromCharCode(0x2190) to compare left arrow character in javascript. If you alert  this then you can see left arrow character is alerted.